# How to query all rows in a dataset using SAQL

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

We have a dataset with millions of rows in Salesforce Wave. We want to fetch records using SAQL.

We used the below SAQL to get the records. And we executed this SAQL using "services/data/v34.0/wave/query" endpoint

> {"query":"q = load \"datasetId/versionId\"; q = foreach q generate field1 as 'display_name';"}

This fetches 10000 record. How can we fetch the remaining record? Do we have something like queryMore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify a limit, the default limit is 10,000

[SAQL Limit Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_eql.meta/bi_dev_guide_eql/bi_eql_statement_limit.htm)

here's a blog from Andrew about [downloading a dataset](http://www.andrewprice.me/blog/2015/7/5/downloading-a-dataset-in-salesforce-analytics-cloud) where he talks about changing the limit and querying more records.. but the maximum he mentions is around 75,000 after which it times out.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Vamsi - Yes - the only way I can see this being achievable is to augment another column/dataset and then in the query add the grouping.. With this being the case.. you will have to split this into 75k segments. I would test this.. this may have changed on new update.. but essentially all I am using is the https://github.com/forcedotcom/Analytics-Cloud-Dataset-Utils tool to download data. I havnt tested using the API.